# Java addAll(collection) vs new ArrayList(collection)

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

Why do i get different behaviors with:

1. `Collection col2 = new ArrayList(col);`
2. `Collection col2 = new ArrayList();`
   `col2.addAll(col)`

I'm working with viewers, and the code is complex, and i'm trying to explain the "root" of the problem. Another interesting fact is the next one...

```
//IF i use this code i have the correct behavior in my app:
public void updateCollection(Collection<Object> col) {
    this.objectCollection.clear();
    this.objectCollection.addAll(col);
}

//IF i use this code i have unexpected behavior in my app:
public void updateCollection(Collection<Object> col) {
    this.objectCollection=new ArrayList(col);
}
```

Comment: please clarify, which exact behavior is confusing for you?

Comment: My code is having different behaviors using a) or b). In my mind, both operations will lead to the same result, but apparently they do NOT. Something is different.

Comment: You're still too vague. What happens? What happens not? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) along with the (un)expected results at your environment.

Comment: Something is wrong with your understanding.  `new ArrayList(col)` *works*.  You have another problem and have not given us enough information to determine what it might be.

Comment: i'm following logic... if i do "new ArrayList" the code does NOT work. With "clear & AddAll" it Does. That's the only thing i change in the code.

Comment: what is that "unexpected behavior"? Sounds like some other code keeps a reference to that particular collection instance and keeps on using that collection even if you have assigned a new collection instance to the field. I guess "objectCollection" field is not private, is it?

Comment: Looking at your edit, in the case of the working code, you are adding the information to an already-existing ArrayList.  In the case of the non-working code, you're creating a new one.  If, for instance, another entity has direct access to the pre-existing ArrayList, the second bit of code won't be changing that entity's copy of it.  Maybe that's your problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This code works:

```
public void updateCollection(Collection<Object> col) {
    this.objectCollection.clear();
    this.objectCollection.addAll(col);
}
```

But this introduces problems:

```
public void updateCollection(Collection<Object> col) {
    this.objectCollection = new ArrayList(col);
}
```

I suspect that this variation on your first method would introduce identical problems:

```
public void updateCollection(Collection<Object> col) {
    this.objectCollection = new ArrayList();
    this.objectCollection.clear();
    this.objectCollection.addAll(col);
}
```

Why? Evidently you have another reference to `objectCollection` in use somewhere. Somewhere in your code, another object is saying (for instance):

```
myCopyOfObjectCollection = theOtherObject.objectCollection;
```

If you're using a *getter*, that doesn't change the underlying behavior - you are still keeping another *reference* around.

So if on initial assignment, say, the collection contained {1, 2, 3}, you start out with:

- `this.objectCollection`: {1, 2, 3}
- `that.copyOfObjectCollection`: {1, 2, 3}

When you assign a *new* ArrayList to `this.objectCollection`, and populate it with, say, {4, 5, 6}, you get this:

- `this.objectCollection`: {4, 5, 6}
- `that.copyOfObjectCollection`: {1, 2, 3}

So `that` is still pointing to the original ArrayList.

Answer (score 7):

```
Collection col2 = new ArrayList(col);
```

will create a new `ArrayList` with size `col.size()` (+10%) and copy all elements from `col` into that array.

```
Collection col2 = new ArrayList();
```

will create a new ArrayList with initial size of 10 (at least in Sun implementation).

```
col2.addAll(col);
```

will copy all elements from `col` into the end of the `col2` `ArrayList`, enlarging the backing array size, if needed.

So, depending on your `col` collection size, the behavior will be a bit different, but not too much.

**It is preferable to use the first option** - that will avoid at least one extra backing array expansion operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public List getAdminImIdsWithValidShortNames(){
    return adminImIdsWithValidShortNames;
}

public void setAdminImIdsWithValidShortNames(List adminImIdsWithValidShortNames){
    this.adminImIdsWithValidShortNames=adminImIdsWithValidShortNames;
}
```

I think, easy is beautiful, just generator setter/getter method is a good habit.
if you first clear, then addAll, the list need to clear all elements of list, then addAll will be extra backing array expansion operation, that's not science.

just replacement, this variable will be point to new List, the old list will be auto-GC.